# Efficient Filtering on a huge data frame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra table with 500 million rows. I would like to filter based on a field which is a partition key in Cassandra using spark.

Can you suggest the best possible/efficient approach to filter in Spark/Spark SQL based on the list keys which is also a pretty large.

Basically i need only those rows from the Cassandra table which are present in the list of keys.

We are using DSE and its features.
The approach i am using is taking lot of time roughly around an hour.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by a large list?

Comment: I want to join 2 data sets. Cassandra table with 500+ millions records and a list of key(i.e say object_id). The end results should be only those Cassandra table rows whose object_id match in the list. I am using join which is taking loads of time and i want to prevent that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked `repartitionByCassandraReplica` and `joinWithCassandraTable` ?

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/75719dfe0e175b3e0bb1c06127ad4e6930c73ece/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12

> `joinWithCassandraTable` utilizes the java drive to execute a single
>   query for every partition required by the source RDD so no un-needed
>   data will be requested or serialized. This means a join between any
>   RDD and a Cassandra Table can be performed without doing a full table
>   scan. When performed between two Cassandra Tables which share the same
>   partition key this will not require movement of data between machines.
>   In all cases this method will use the source RDD's partitioning and
>   placement for data locality.
>
> The method `repartitionByCassandraReplica` can be used to relocate data
>   in an RDD to match the replication strategy of a given table and
>   keyspace. The method will look for partition key information in the
>   given RDD and then use those values to determine which nodes in the
>   Cluster would be responsible for that data.